# Gridview, allow background canvas to draw outside of view

Tags: android, gridview, canvas

I'm developing an app for Android, a small notepad app.
In my app I use a Gridview for create a grid of 2*X size and in each cell
I has a LinearLayout call AbstractNote that has in task to show a preview of each save
note in the app.

I what my AbstractNote to has a background image that is some bit rotate for show
the preview more beautifully. But my problems is while i rotate the image some of it falls outside of the AbstractNote Area, and I'not find a good way to show this to.

I has try to use `View.setAnimation(...)` and it works but give me rugged image and text,
and I has try to crate a custom Drawable (set as `AbstractNote.setBackgroundDrawable(...)`) that give me smooth image but not show the full image.

Do note, My target android is 2.1 and I not use `View.setRotation(...)`

Use a `View.setAnimation` for do this but get rugged image and text

[image]

Use custom drawable, but can't paint outside of the cell.

[image]

If somebody know how to fix it, by fix the rugged image and text in attempted 1 or
how to draw image outside the cell in attempted 2, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I has finally find a solution on the problem, the solution is not very good but work, the idea was to draw the cells item directly draw the background on the GridView and not the GridView childen/item

I Create a new GridView as:

```
public class NoteGridView extends GridView {
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    if (count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
            // For each of my childen draw it backgrund that allow to draw bg that is bigger then cell.
            View childAt = this.getChildAt(i);
            if (childAt instanceof AbstractNote) {
                final AbstractNote note = (AbstractNote) childAt;
                // Set the zero point to the start of the childen, then call the childen draw methods.
                canvas.save();
                canvas.translate(childAt.getLeft(), childAt.getTop());
                note.drawBackground(canvas);
                canvas.restore();
            }
        }
    }
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

And in my children `AbstractNote` I add the method `drawBackground`, this do that background I what to draw in my `AbstractNote` is now draw on the GridView canvas that is much bigger then the small canvas I has in `AbstractNote`