# Android: usage of grid view as canvas

Tags: android

How can we write anything on a grid canvas so that at the end we are able to find staring and ending point in form of axis like user start writing from  x=90.00 and y=80.0 and stop writing or his fingure  stop at x=150 and y=170 in java android ...

Comment: think this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315965/gridview-allow-background-canvas-to-draw-outside-of-view

Comment: no sir its not like that